# Recode multiple variables in R based on logic

Tags: r, plyr, apply

I'm interested in see if you can loop through a dataset and recode variables with a single function:

data would look like this:

```
V1 V2 V3 R1 R2 R3
-----------------
a   r  s  5  5  0
a   b  c  0  1  0
e   r  r  5  6  6
```

I'd like to recode just the three R variables. In the actual data set there are at least 50 of the R variables to recode. The output should look something like this where anything greater than 0 should be 1 and 0 remain 0:

```
V1 V2 V3 R1 R2 R3
-----------------
a   r  s  1  1  0
a   b  c  0  1  0
e   r  r  1  1  1
```

Comment: you can use bitwAnd(a,b), and and each value with 1

Comment: `df[4:6][df[4:6] > 0] <- 1` should work

Comment: interesting I'm not familiar with that I'll take a look and see if it helps

Comment: Thxs Richard that doesn't seem to be working should there be comma in there?

Comment: I tried Richard Scriven's answer it didn't work for me and I thought there was suppose to be a comma in the square brackets

Comment: Well I don't know.  Do you have a matrix or a data frame? What do you mean by "didn't work"? Please show us what you've tried

Comment: df[4:6][df[,4:6] > 0] <- 1 got Richard Scriven's answer to work it was just missing a comma inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be try sapply()

(DF is your dataset)

```
DF[,4:6]<-sapply(DF[,4:6],function(x)ifelse(x>0,1,0))
```

Comment: Great I'll give this a shot in a few

Comment: This works great for recoding everything. Is there a way to maintain the original dataframe with all its variables while recoding just that select range of variables?

Comment: @moku hmmm...this should retain the whole dataframe including the variables not converted. Did you only run the right hand side of the script by any chance?

Comment: Yeah I see now so your answer is def the most correct!  However when you add the comma into Richard Scriven's answer it is actually much faster. Thanks for the help very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could try an -ifelse- statement 
1) loop over all variables in your dataset
2) decide whether they are numeric or not
3) recode them

like this:

```
 for (i in 1:ncol(mydata) {
   if (is.numeric(mydata[,i] == "TRUE" {
      mydata[,i] <- ifelse(mydata[,i] > 0, 1, 0 )
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: some of the variables that shouldn't be recoded are numeric